# Importing modules in embedded python

Tags: python, python-embedding

I'm trying to get module imports to work in embeddable python, but it doesn't want to work

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\winpy\python-3.10.10-embed-win32>type run_scripts\script.py
from module_test import test

print("Hello world!")
print(test())

C:\Users\test\Desktop\winpy\python-3.10.10-embed-win32>type run_scripts\module_test.py
def test():
    return "Test!"

C:\Users\test\Desktop\winpy\python-3.10.10-embed-win32>@python.exe run_scripts\script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\winpy\python-3.10.10-embed-win32\run_scripts\script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_test import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_test'
```

Why is the module not being imported? I tried changing PYTHONPATH but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are running the script from is not automatically on the search path of the interpreter when using embeddable python.

To solve this you can add the directory which holds your modules to the python310._pth file, which is stored in the embedded python folder. If your modules are placed in your run_scripts folder, you'll have to add the run_scripts folder to the file like this:

```
python310.zip
.
run_scripts
```

For your reference, I found some information on this in the python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-finding-modules

Answer (score 0):

The `embed.zip` Windows Python distribution requires some tweaks. It does not run correctly "out of the box".  I created a PowerShell script, [`PythonEmbed4Win.ps1`](https://github.com/jtmoon79/PythonEmbed4Win), to install the `embed.zip` Python distribution downloaded from the Internet, and then tweak the installation so it will run without errors.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jtmoon79/PythonEmbed4Win/main/PythonEmbed4Win.ps1" -OutFile "PythonEmbed4Win.ps1"

.\PythonEmbed4Win.ps1 -Version 3.10
```